# How to wait for multiple fetch to complete, aggregate the result and post it to another URL

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch data from multiple URLs, for example consider a.com, b.com, c.com etc. Consider there are ~500 such URLs. Some of these are up and some can be down which is not known at runtime. I need to aggregate the output received from all active URLs and post them to another URL. I am new to js and could not complete the aggregation with the below code. Please let me know what changes are needed here.

```
<script>
let resultVal="";
async function apiRequest(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
        }
        let myRet=response.text();
       // resultVal=resultVal+"<br\>"+url+" ::: "+myRet;
        return myRet;
      })
      .then(function(text) {
        resultVal=resultVal+"Url: "+url+"Inner content::: "+text+"<br>";
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error"+error); 
      })
});

}

async function getData() {
let urlList = ["http://www.a.com", "http://www.b.com", "http://www.c.com"];

Promise.all(urlList.map(u=>apiRequest(u)))
.then(function(res){
    console.log('Promise.all', res);
})
.catch(function(err){
   console.error('err', err);
});
}

async function callFetch() {
const res= await getData();
}

callFetch();
fetch('http://www/xyz.com', {method: 'post', body: 'Response: '+resultVal});

</script>
```

Comment: a) never a reason to put a fetch inside a `new Promise` - especially one you never resolve or reject ... just return the fetch instead ... b) you seem to be using Promise.all correctly, the problem is that the Promise from `apiRequest` is perpetually pending c) in general, you don't need `async function` if you never `await`

Comment: Thanks Bravo. The issue I am facing is that posting response to xyz.com happens before the aggregation from all fetches is complete(resultVal is empty at that time). I started with only promise.all and later added the async hoping it helps. But unfortunately didn't.  Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: that would be because `getData` doesn't `await` the promise returned by `Promise.all`, and `callFetch` returns a Promise, the result of calling `getData` but you don't wait for that to resolve either, so the last fetch is just run with `resultVal = ''` - with the issues in `apiRequest` (the promise remains pending forever), the fact that `getData` doesn't wait for the promise to resolve, and the fact that you call `callFetch` without waiting for result, your code has no chance at all to ever work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issues in your code are as follows

`apiRequest`: returns a `new Promise` that is never resolved

`getData`: doesn't wait for `Promise.all` to resolve

`callFetch`: is asynchronous, but when called is not waited for

other issues:

`getData` is `async` - but you never `await`
`apiRequest` is `async` - but you never `await`
`resultVal` could be "built" in any order, depending on the order in which the fetches receive a response.

Fixed code

```
async function apiRequest(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
    }
    let text = await response.text();
    return "Url: " + url + "Inner content::: " + text + "<br>";
}

function getData() {
    let urlList = ["http://www.a.com", "http://www.b.com", "http://www.c.com"];

    return Promise.all(urlList.map(u => apiRequest(u)));
}

async function callFetch() {
    let res = await getData();
    return res.join('');
}

callFetch()
.then(resultVal => {
    fetch('http://www/xyz.com', {
        method: 'post',
        body: 'Response: ' + resultVal
    });
})
.catch(err => console.log('err', err));
```

In a browser where top-level `await` is allowed, the lines after the `callFetch` function can also be written

```
try {
    const resultVal = await callFetch();
    await fetch('http://www/xyz.com', {
        method: 'post',
        body: 'Response: ' + resultVal
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log('err', err);
}
```

But I'd hold off using this for now, or do it like this if the code happens to be inside an `async` function

Comment: Thank you very much. How do we handle the timeout error when some of these sites are down? The requirement here is that some of the sites are down, but we still need to fetch data from other available sites. I tried putting a catch for both fetch and await to ignore the timeout; but both did not help unfortunately.

Comment: don't use `Promise.all` use [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) - with the necessary adjustments, since each result is no longer just the result, it's `{status: "fulfilled", value: whatever}` for success and `{status: "rejected",  reason: some error}` ...

Comment: Thank you. Your inputs were very helpful